# How do I use different template urls for same component in angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, components, reusability, angular-components

I've implemented a component  in following way

```
angular.module('moduleName')
        .component('myComponent', {
            templateUrl: 'templatePath1.tpl.html',
            controller: myController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindings: {
                b1: '&',
                b2: '&'
            }
        });
```

I'm using that as `<my-component b1="someThing1" b2="someThing2"></my-component>`

Now, I want to use the same `myController` with another template residing at `templatePath2.tpl.html`.

One way is to create another component `myComponent2`,

```
angular.module('moduleName')
        .component('myComponent2', {
            templateUrl: 'templatePath2.tpl.html',
            controller: myController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindings: {
                b1: '&',
                b2: '&'
            }
        });
```

Is there any way I can use previous component and select templateUrl based on an attr? If yes, how should one do that?

Comment: are you getting an error while creating the mycomponent2 with the same template url and controller?

Answer (score 0):

`templateUrl` can be a function, that gets the element and the attributes as arguments:

```
angular.module('moduleName')
    .component('myComponent', {
        templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
                      return 'templatePath' + attrs.x + '.tpl.html';
                     },

<my-component x="1"></my-component>
```